# Linux character device driver to return a dice roll - accessed by read() command

Tags: c, linux, random, linux-device-driver

We are doing a project involving Yahtzee in my intro to systems class, and I don't quite understand how the device driver works. My Yahtzee program is completely functional, but I just read in from a file of random ints currently.

I have most of my driver set up using an 'example' driver that was given to us. The goal is to return a dice roll to the user. I'm having trouble with the algorithm - I'm using the following function as a helper function to return a single byte:

```
unsigned char get_random_byte(int max) {
         unsigned char c;
         get_random_bytes(&c, 1);
         return c%max;
}
```

I know that I should be taking the bits and combining them before performing a mod 6 op on total and adding one to write to the file pointer. In pseudo code:

```
(TOTAL_OF_BITS % 6) + 1
```

However, with the parameters of the function, I'm not sure how to do this. It is supposed to work with the read command:

```
static ssize_t dice_read(struct file * file, char * buf, size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
```

I compared it to the read command read(dice[i], sizeof(int), 1, fp) to find that I should be assigned the result to file, but apart from that I'm not sure how to proceed. It would be dependent on the buf variable as well for the size right?

Part of the problem is my knowledge on device drivers is pretty shaky to begin with. Could someone please help me out? I appreciate the time and effort.

Comment: You need to concentrate on the driver first. Forget about the program. You need to load the driver, the driver should create a special file like `/dev/dice`, and you should be able to `od -t x1 /dev/dice` from the terminal and see random bytes from 1 to 6 scroll by. Then you can return to the program and adapt it to use the driver.

Comment: I just did the Yahtzee program because it was trivial - its the driver I'm having issues with. Ideally, if I could do you what you just said, it would work great and I wouldn't really need to adapt it. I'm having issues coming up with the driver so that when I run `od -t x1 /dev/dice` that it returns the number. I know to create the special file, but what is the algorithm for the driver?

Comment: There are many possible implementations. If you are not told to use a high-quality secure PRNG, you may choose something simple, such as a linear congruent generator, or a middle-square generator (google these things up).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: I ended up using a different method, but it seems my issue was just understanding how device_drivers work. While I don't completely understand them still, I'll upload my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the read method I used:

```
static ssize_t dice_read(struct file * file, char * buf,
                          size_t count, loff_t *ppos)
{    
  int i;
  char* data;    

  if(count == 0){
    return 0;
  }
  data = kmalloc(count, GFP_KERNEL);

  for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
    data[i] = get_random_byte(6) + 1;
  }

  if(copy_to_user(buf, data, count)){
   kfree(data);
  }


  *ppos+=count;
  return *ppos;
}
```

And to restate, the method I have for random numbers is:

```
unsigned char get_random_byte(int max) {
     unsigned char c;
     get_random_bytes(&c, 1);
     return c%max;
}
```